# Is coupon collection concentrated?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, coupon-collector, concentration-of-measure

Say you buy $m$ coupons out of $n$ possible types, and each is given you randomly with replacement. It's standard that the amount of time you need to wait to get $k$ coupons is approximately in expectation
$$
n[\log (n) - \log (n - k)]
$$
and inverting this you'd expect that the number of types of coupons you get after buying $m$ of them is about
$$
n(1 - e^{-m/n})
$$
My question is, do you get concentration about this quantity? That is, I'm looking for a statement like: with high probability, if you buy $m$ coupons you are unlikely to be very far from having exactly $n(1 - e^{-m/n})$ distinct types of coupons. I'd be ok with a factor difference, but ideally I want to be only lower order terms away from this expectation.

Comment: In which $(n,m)$ regime?

Comment: @Did I'm interested mostly in the $m \sim n$ regime. In the $m \ll n$ regime it's almost trivial to get multiplicative concentration, since you never expect more than, say, six-fold collisions for the case of $m \sim \sqrt{n}$. However I'm not sure how common collisions are so maybe that would still be interesting --- that is, the fluctuations are probably lower-order.

Answer (score 1):

The expected distinct number collected is $$n\left(1- \left(1-\frac1n\right)^m\right)$$ which, as you say, can be close to $n\left(1- e^{-m/n}\right)$

The variance of the distinct number collected is $$n\left(1-\frac1n\right)^m + n^2\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)^m - n^2\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{2m}$$ which empirically for large $m=n$ seems to be about $0.0972n$, while for large $m \approx n \log(n)$ seems to be about $1$, and for large $m\approx  n H_n$ seems to be about $0.56$. For large $m \approx \sqrt{n}$, the variance seems to be about $0.5$

You could for example use the standard deviation (the square root of the variance) as a measure of spread

Comment: Where can I find a reference for this?